# How do I prevent "orphaned" child models from being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following models in Rails 4:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I can create a new customer with a new order, and save them both at the same time by saving the parent:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > customer = Customer.new
2.0.0-p247 :002 > order = customer.orders.build
2.0.0-p247 :003 > customer.save
2.0.0-p247 :004 > order.customer_id
 => 3
```

This works fine. However, Rails will allow me to save just the order:

```
2.0.0-p247 :005 > customer = Customer.new
2.0.0-p247 :006 > order = customer.orders.build
2.0.0-p247 :007 > order.save
2.0.0-p247 :008 > order.customer_id
 => nil
```

and if I never call `customer.save` then I end up with a database row where `orders.customer_id` is `null`.

The answer would seem to be adding a `validates` line in the order model for its customer parent, but I’ve never been able to find the right formula for this.

1. Adding `validates :customer, presence: true` doesn’t help, because in the above example, the order does have a customer — but it’s a new customer that doesn’t have an ID yet; the `order.save` call succeeds and in the database `orders.customer_id` is `null`.
2. Adding `validates :customer, associated: true` doesn’t help either; `order.save` succeeds and in the database `orders.customer_id` is `null`.
3. Adding `validates :customer_id, presence: true` does make `order.save` fail — but it also keeps the `customer.save` with new child orders from succeeding, because Rails checks the validity of all `customer.orders` before the `customer.save` happens.

I know the TDD principle is “test your own code, not someone else’s” and I want to trust Rails to do its job. But it seems without closing this loophole, I could accidentally write code that saves an orphan order and end up with invalid data in my database. I don't want to have to litter my code with checks for `order.customer` existing.

What’s the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would rollback and change the migration file to not allow null customer_id field.

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.integer :customer_id, {null: false} #this would work?

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :orders, :customer_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting. I had already tried this (normally I prevent nulls on _id fields so I can index them), but I also had `default: 0` -- which just changes the problem from preventing null to preventing 0. But you're right -- if you use `null: false` without a default, the database constraint will prevent `order.save`, but `customer.save` will still work.

Answer (score 0):

no need to check for `order.customer` if you use `Customer.create` instead of `Customer.new`